# How to get the html value inside the pre tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery to set my html value for the pre tag like as following,

```
$(function() {
    $("#myPre").html("myText");
});
```

In the same program, I need to get the html value for the pre tag (myPre -> is my pre tag id). How to do this? Please anyone help me.

Comment: var html = $("#myPre").html();

Comment: thanks @AtheistP3ace it worked.

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery html function when not given any arguments gets the html value of the matched elements instead of setting it.

```
var html = $("#myPre").html();
```

You can read more about how it works and other features here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I am just learning jquery now. Thanks for your help and for the link @atheistP3ace

Comment: No worries. Its has a big API and not everything is immediately obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$.ready(function(){
    //To set html
    $("#mypre").html("some html");
    //To get html
    var html=$("#mypre").html();
});
```